# User account design and security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3

Before I begin, I am using Ruby on Rails and the Devise gem for user authentication.

Hi, I was doing some research about account security and I found a blog post about the topic awhile ago but I can no longer find it again. I read something about when making a login system you should have 1 model for User, this contains a user's username, encrypted password, and email. You should also have a model for a user's Account. This contains everything else. A User has an Account.

I don't know if I'm explaining this correctly since I haven't seen the blog post for several months and I lost my bookmark.

Could someone explain how and why I should or shouldn't do this. My application deals with money so I need to cover my bases with security.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this is the same thing as Django's built-in authentication mechanism. The User model is provided by the core framework, but you can provide a Profile model yourself to store any data that the User model does not represent.

Comment: An app I've inherited relates any number of users with a single account. Perhaps to support different login credentials over time?

Answer (score 3):

Using different models to handle User (a model that handle basic authentication) and Account (a model that holds all the informations about *what* a user can do, *how*, ...) could give you some plus:

1. storing User's data using a secondary storage system exposing higher security level
2. restricting User's data access by other application artifacts (models, controllers, whatever)
3. making code review and security audit easier

I tend to add personal informations (real name, phone number, ...) to the the User model while exposing operational data about the user in the Account model (nickname, bio, ...).

Comment: Someone reading while I was typing suggested to implement point #1 installing a database in another dimension. I had to share.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like a good architectural decision to keep those models separate because they refer to the different entities: **User** model belongs to auth system and **Account** model belongs to user profile management system. But it all depends. If your models are really tiny(say, 3-5 fields each), you probably couldn't have any advantages from such separation but additional headache. But, if your models are large and, say, **User** model is going to be used much more frequently - then you should think hard about implementing different models for clarity and performance reasons.

Comment: Security practices shouldn't care about how large or tiny your data or how complex your models are. A model holding my SSN or my credit card number should be far more hardened than a model holding all my public comments on this website. At least, I would.